# How to tell tox to use PyPI mirrors for installing packages?

Tags: python, testing, pypi, tox

Is there a way to tell the `tox` test automation tool to use the PyPI mirrors while installing all packages (explicit testing dependencies in `tox.ini` and dependencies from `setup.py`)?

For example, `pip install` has a very useful `--use-mirrors` option that adds mirrors to the list of package servers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pip also can be configured using [environment variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#environment-variables), which `tox` lets you [set in the configuration](http://testrun.org/tox/latest//config.html#confval-setenv=MULTI-LINE-LIST):

```
setenv =
    PIP_USE_MIRRORS=...
```

Note that `--use-mirrors` has been deprecated; instead, you can set the `PIP_INDEX_URL` or `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variables, representing the [`--index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-0) and [`--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-extra-index-url) command-line options.

For example:

```
setenv = 
    PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=http://example.org/index
```

would add `http://example.org/index` as an alternative index server, used if the main index doesn't have a package.

Comment: [`indexserver`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-indexserver) is now deprecated. See a [discussion on the topic](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1357). The doc has been updated in this [_PR_](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/pull/1728). See ["_Using a different default PyPI URL_"](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#using-a-different-default-pypi-url) and ["_Installing dependencies from multiple PyPI servers_"](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#installing-dependencies-from-multiple-pypi-servers) for the current recommendation.

Comment: @sinoroc: thanks for the heads-up, I've removed indexserver altogether.

Comment: I want to add that `setenv` should be under each environment, not under `[tox]`.

Answer (score 13):

Since `indexserver` is [deprecated](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-indexserver) and would be removed and `--use-mirrors` is [deprecated](https://github.com/learning-unlimited/ESP-Website/issues/1758) as well, you can use install_command (in your environment section):

```
[testenv:my_env]
install_command=pip install --index-url=https://my.index-mirror.com --trusted-host=my.index-mirror.com {opts} {packages}
```

Comment: See ["_Using a different default PyPI URL_"](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#using-a-different-default-pypi-url) and ["_Installing dependencies from multiple PyPI servers_"](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#installing-dependencies-from-multiple-pypi-servers) for the current recommendations.

Answer (score 7):

Tox can be configured to install dependencies and packages from a different default PyPI server:

- as tox command line argument

  ```
  tox -i http://pypi.my-alternative-index.org
  ```
- using `tox.ini`

  ```
  [tox]
  indexserver =
      default = http://pypi.my-alternative-index.org
  ```

[Link to Tox documentation on using a different default PyPI url](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html?highlight=index%20server#using-a-different-default-pypi-url)

Comment: [_`indexserver`_ is deprecated](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-indexserver).

Answer (score 2):

From the pip docs:

> pip’s command line options can be set with environment variables using the format PIP_<UPPER_LONG_NAME> . Dashes (-) have to be replaced with underscores (_).

Source: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables

This translates into setting the following environment variables:

```sh
PIP_INDEX_URL=https://server1/pypi/simple
PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=https://server2/pypi/simple
```

So, with tox, you can e.g. set:

```
[testenv]
setenv = 
    PIP_INDEX_URL=https://server1/pypi/simple
    PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=https://server2/pypi/simple
```

However, you can only specify one extra index url with PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL. If you need multiple ones, pip recommends appending multiple `--extra-index-url <URL>` after the pip command so if you need more than one extra index URL, you could possibly utilize tox's [`install_command`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command):

```
[testenv]
install_command =
    python -m pip install {opts} {packages} --extra-index-url <URL1> --extra-index-url <URL2>
```

Comment: It is apparently valid to specify multiple space-separated values per _pip_ environment variable: `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://charlie.dev/simple https://delta.dev/simple"`. -- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can define an alternative index-url for pip by passing the environment variable PIP_INDEX_URL to the `pip` environment using `setenv =`  as in

```
[testenv]
setenv =
    PIP_INDEX_URL = https://pypi.my-alternative-index.org
```

If PIP_INDEX_URL was already defined in the environment running `tox` and you want to pass it to the environment running `pip`, use the following solution that will first look at the current environment value for PIP_INDEX_URL and if it was not defined it will default to the default value passed:

```
[testenv]
setenv =
    PIP_INDEX_URL = {env:PIP_INDEX_URL:https://pypi.my-alternative-index.org}
```

I also in some ocations I had to set `PIP_TRUSTED_HOST` as in

```
[testenv]
setenv =
    PIP_INDEX_URL = {env:PIP_INDEX_URL:https://pypi.my-alternative-index.org}
    PIP_TRUSTED_HOST = {env:PIP_TRUSTED_HOST:pypi.my-alternative-index.org}
```

Comment: This would be interesting if this answer expanded on why it is different or better than the already existing answers.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I have improved the answer to include how it is different from other answers.