# How to configure tox to use multiple index urls?

Tags: python, tox

Currently in tox, we can add a default index url for python packages. This is done like this:

```
indexserver =
      default = <index url I want to add>
```

**My query:** Can we add multiple index urls for searching python packages in tox ?

Comment: `indexserver` was [deprectaed](https://tox.wiki/en/legacy/config.html#conf-indexserver) in tox 3 and removed in tox 4. Set `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable instead. For extra indices set `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` or set `install_command`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65324808/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btox%5D+multiple+index

Comment: @phd Please create an answer so we can upvote :-)

Comment: @JürgenGmach I copied everything from existing answers (except for deprecated `indexserver` — I wrote about it before I searched SO, but it also mentioned in comments) so the question could be just closed as a duplicate.